ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED for selenium webdriver HTTPS scraping attempt
I'm currently working on a scraping project and facing some issues with using a proxy from Webshare. This is my first time using a proxy, and I can't seem to access the target webpage.
Every time I try to open the webpage, I encounter an ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED error. I've tried various methods, including writing custom Chrome extensions to handle the authentification, but nothing seems to work.
Help!
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = {
'proxy': {
    'http': 'http://user:pass@proxyIP:proxyPort',
    'https': 'http://user:pass@proxyIP:proxyPort',
    'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
    }
}

# Path to ChromeDriver
chrome_driver_path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe"
service = Service(chrome_driver_path)
chrome_options = Options()

# Initialize Chrome driver with seleniumwire options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options, seleniumwire_options=options)

driver.get('https://example.com')
driver.implicitly_wait(8)

driver.quit()


always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED means that Python can not establish a http connection to the configured proxy. Something seems to be wrong with your proxy config.
